# How to edit in multiple elements in an xml in android studio

Tags: android, xml

Here is my xml code

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="3" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="4" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="5" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="6" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="7" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="8" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="9" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="10" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="11" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="12" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Now i want to add the below code to all the textView elements

```
android:textSize="20sp"
android:textColor="#004D40"
```

but to do these i have to copy and paste the code in all the elements.
It becomes very tedious when we have to make iterative changes and when there are high number of elements.

Comment: I usually do `Ctrl + R` to replace, then, in your case, I replace string

'
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"`
to 

`
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="#004D40"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By this you can apply to all textviews

```
     //which ever you default theme is write textAppearance item inside it.
     <style name="theme" parent="android:Theme">

    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance</item>
     </style>

     <style name="text_views" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
     <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
     <item name="android:textColor">#004D40</item>
      </style>
```

further more you can mention `#004D40` in `colors.xml` and `20sp` in `dimens.xml`

Answer (score 0):

you should use Style Resource.

XML file for the style (saved in res/values/styles.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="CustomText" parent="@style/Text">
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#004D40</item>
</style>  </resources>
```

XML file that applies the style to a TextView (saved in res/layout/):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <TextView
        style="@style/CustomText"
        android:text="1" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/CustomText"
        android:text="2" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/CustomText"
        android:text="3" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/CustomText"
        android:text="4" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/CustomText"
        android:text="5" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/CustomText"
        android:text="6" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/CustomText"
        android:text="7" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/CustomText"
        android:text="8" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/CustomText"
        android:text="9" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/CustomText"
        android:text="10" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/CustomText"
        android:text="11" />

    <TextView
       style="@style/CustomText"
        android:text="12" />

    <TextView  
       style="@style/CustomText"
       android:text="13" />
</LinearLayout>
```

only change one place.